# Excel formula for data validation using regex

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do data validation using excel on a column 
of the type:

> year followed by "-" followed by another year.

example 2010-2011
Can this be done using excel formulas? Can we use regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula (assumes A1 contains value to validate):

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=9, MID(A1,5,1)="-", ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,4)+0),ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,4)+0))
```

This will correctly identify the following examples:

1. 2010-2011 (valid)
2. abc-2011 (invalid)
3. 2010-abc-2011 (invalid)

Comment: The +0 trick is nice. I had a similar idea but was thrown by the fact that Left (and Mid) makes the result a string. I was looking at cumbersome expressions like NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT(... etc.

Comment: Can i apply it to an entire column instead of one cell?

Comment: @rrgirish yes - copy the formula down the entire column